# SAS/SQL - Create SELECT Statement Using Custom Function

Tags: sql, sas

**UPDATE**

Given this new approach using `INTNX` I think I can just use a loop to simplify things even more.  What if I made an array:

```
data;
    array period [4] $ var1-var4 ('day' 'week' 'month' 'year');
run;
```

And then tried to make a loop for each element:

```
%MACRO sqlloop;
  proc sql;
    %DO k = 1 %TO dim(period);  /* in case i decide to drop something from array later */
      %LET bucket = &period(k)
      CREATE TABLE output.t_&bucket AS (
        SELECT INTX( "&bucket.", date_field, O, 'E') AS test FROM table);
    %END
  quit;
%MEND
%sqlloop
```

This doesn't quite work, but it captures the idea I want.  It could just run the query for each of those values in INTX.  Does that make sense?

---

I have a couple of prior questions that I'm merging into one.  I got some really helpful advice on the others and hopefully this can tie it together.

I have the following function that creates a dynamic string to populate a `SELECT` statement in a SAS `proc sql;` code block:

```
proc fcmp outlib = output.funcs.test;
    function sqlSelectByDateRange(interval $, date_field $) $;
        day = date_field||" AS day, ";
        week = "WEEK("||date_field||") AS week, ";
        month = "MONTH("||date_field||") AS month, ";
        year = "YEAR("||date_field||") AS year, ";

        IF interval = "week" THEN
            do;
                day = '';
            end;
        IF interval = "month" THEN
            do;
                day = '';
                week = '';
            end;
        IF interval = "year" THEN
            do;
                day = '';
                week = '';
                month = '';
            end;
        where_string = day||week||month||year;
    return(where_string);
    endsub;
quit;
```

I've verified that this creates the kind of string I want:

```
data _null_;
    q = sqlSelectByDateRange('month', 'myDateColumn');
    put q =;
run;
```

This yields:

```
q=MONTH(myDateColumn) AS month, YEAR(myDateColumn) AS year,
```

This is exactly what I want the SQL string to be.  From prior questions, I believe I need to call this function in a `MACRO`.  Then I want something like this:

```
%MACRO sqlSelectByDateRange(interval, date_field);
  /* Code I can't figure out */
%MEND

PROC SQL;
  CREATE TABLE output.t AS (
    SELECT 
      %sqlSelectByDateRange('month', 'myDateColumn')
    FROM
      output.myTable
  );
QUIT;
```

I am having trouble understanding how to make the code call this macro and interpret as part of the SQL SELECT string.  I've tried some of the previous examples in other answers but I just can't make it work.  I'm hoping this more specific question can help me fill in this missing step so I can learn how to do it in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

First, you should be able to use [%SYSFUNC](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#z3514sysfunc.htm) to call your custom function.

```
%MACRO sqlSelectByDateRange(interval, date_field);
    %SYSFUNC( sqlSelectByDateRange(&interval., &date_field.) )
%MEND;
```

Note that you should not use quotation marks when calling a function via SYSFUNC. Also, [you cannot use SYSFUNC with FCMP functions until SAS 9.2](http://support.sas.com/kb/40/702.html). If you are using an earlier version, this will not work.

Second, you have a trailing comma in your select clause. You may need a dummy column as in the following:

```
PROC SQL;
  CREATE TABLE output.t AS (
    SELECT 
      %sqlSelectByDateRange('month', 'myDateColumn')
      0 AS dummy
    FROM
      output.myTable
  );
QUIT;
```

(Notice that there is no comma before `dummy`, as the comma is already embedded in your macro.)

---

**UPDATE**

I read your comment on another answer:

> I also need to be able to do it for different date ranges and on a very ad-hoc basis, so it's something where I want to say "by month from june to december" or "weekly for two years" etc when someone makes a request.

I think I can recommend an easier way to accopmlish what you are doing. First, I'll create a very simple dataset with dates and values. The dates are spread throughout different days, weeks, months and years:

```
DATA Work.Accounts;

    Format      Opened      yymmdd10.
                Value       dollar14.2
                ;

    INPUT       Opened      yymmdd10.
                Value       dollar14.2
                ;

DATALINES;
2012-12-31  $90,000.00
2013-01-01 $100,000.00
2013-01-02 $200,000.00
2013-01-03 $150,000.00
2013-01-15 $250,000.00
2013-02-10 $120,000.00
2013-02-14 $230,000.00
2013-03-01 $900,000.00
RUN;
```

You can now use the `INTNX` function to create a third column to round the "Opened" column to some time period, such as a `'WEEK'`, `'MONTH'`, or `'YEAR'` (see this [complete list](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000990883.htm#a001115672)):

```
%LET Period = YEAR;

PROC SQL NOPRINT;

    CREATE TABLE Work.PeriodSummary AS
    SELECT   INTNX( "&Period.", Opened, 0, 'E' ) AS Period_End FORMAT=yymmdd10.
           , SUM( Value )                        AS TotalValue FORMAT=dollar14.
    FROM     Work.Accounts
    GROUP BY Period_End
    ;

QUIT;
```

Output for `WEEK`:

```
Period_End   TotalValue
2013-01-05     $540,000
2013-01-19     $250,000
2013-02-16     $350,000
2013-03-02     $900,000
```

Output for `MONTH`:

```
Period_End   TotalValue
2012-12-31      $90,000
2013-01-31     $700,000
2013-02-28     $350,000
2013-03-31     $900,000
```

Output for `YEAR`:

```
Period_End   TotalValue
2012-12-31      $90,000
2013-12-31   $1,950,000
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try.  Thanks for the info on the dummy column.  In the actual code there will be a couple other columns in every instance, so it shouldn't be an issue here but I can see that being a trouble spot in other queries.

Comment: @JeffreyKramer - Obviously the best approach would be to remove the trailing comma.

Comment: It's giving me a couple of errors.  First was `ERROR: The SQLSELECTBYDATERANG function referenced in the %SYSFUNC or %QSYSFUNC macro function is not found.`  I shortened the function name, verified output worked when entered literally, and reran.  Then it says `54 %sqlSelect('month', 'myDate')
ERROR: The text expression length (65538) exceeds maximum length (65534). The text expression has been truncated to 65534 characters.`  Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @JeffreyKramer - I may have an easier way for you to accopmlish your goals. Check it out above.

Comment: You aren't defining lengths of things in your function, so you risk things being really really big - perhaps that's happening with all of those hand-concatenations (||); CATS/etc. are better as they have predefined default lengths.

Comment: Also - if you can use the INTNX stuff, you should; it's far more flexible and useful to other people.  You can define custom time intervals, also, which can be very helpful.

Comment: Oh my, this is way better than what I was trying to do.  It accomplishes the same goal exactly.  Thanks so much for the help guys.

Comment: @JeffreyKramer - SAS is extremely powerful and flexible. If you find yourself struggling with a mountain of complex code to do something that seems rather straightforward, you should probably stop and see if there isn't a function, etc, to accomplish the task. :)

Answer (score 2):

As Cyborg37 says, you probably should get rid of that trailing comma in your function.  But note you do not really need to create a macro to do this, just use the `%SYSFUNC` function directly:

```
proc sql;
  create table output.t as
  select %sysfunc( sqlSelectByDateRange(month, myDateColumn) )
         * /* to avoid the trailing comma */
  from output.myTable;
quit;
```

Also, although this is a clever use of user-defined functions, it's not very clear why you want to do this.  There are probably better solutions available that will not cause as much potential confusion in your code.  User-defined functions, like user-written macros, can make life easier but they can also create an administrative nightmare.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense Bob.  I get the same error involving length, though.  I'm not sure what that's about.  

As for why, I would be curious to hear your thoughts.  I'm basically going to run some reports that need to be grouped by time horizon (day, week, month, year, etc).  Ideally I would prefer to just run the dataset by day and aggregate it however I wanted.  Unfortunately, one of the main fields I'm querying is distinct individuals, who may differ over weeks and months.  Given the size of the data, I want to perform my COUNT DISTINCT at a given level before I export the summaries.

Comment: I also need to be able to do it for different date ranges and on a very ad-hoc basis, so it's something where I want  to say "by month from june to december" or "weekly for two years" etc when someone makes a request.

Answer (score 1):

I could make all sorts of guesses as to why you're getting errors, but fundamentally, don't do it this way.  You can do exactly what you're trying to do in a data step that is much easier to troubleshoot and much easier to implement than a FCMP function which is really just trying to be a data step anyway.

Steps:
1. Create a dataset that has your possible date pulls.  If you're using this a lot, you can put this in a permanent library that is defined in your SAS AUTOEXEC.
2. Create a macro that pulls the needed date strings from it.
3. If you want, use PROC FCMP to make this a function-style macro, using RUN_MACRO.
4. If you do that, use %SYSFUNC to call it.

Here is something that does this:

1:

```
data pull_list;
infile datalines dlm='|';
length query $50. type $8.;
input type $ typenum query $;
datalines;
day|1|&date_field. as day
week|2|week(&date_field.) as week
month|3|month(&date_field.) as month
year|4|year(&date_field.) as year
;;;;
run;
```

2:

```
%macro pull_list(type=,date_field=);
%let date_field = datevar;
%let type = week;
proc sql noprint;
select query into :sellist separated by ',' 
from pull_list
where typenum >= (select typenum from pull_list where type="&type.");
quit;
%mend pull_list;
```

3:

```
proc fcmp outlib = work.functions.funcs;
   function pull_list(type $,date_field $) $;
      rc = run_macro('pull_list', type,date_field);
      if rc eq 0 then return("&sellist.");
      else return(' ');
   endsub;
run;
```

4:

```
data test;
input datevar 5.;
datalines;
18963
19632
18131
19105
;;;;
run;
option cmplib = (work.functions);

proc sql;
select %sysfunc(pull_list(week,datevar)) from test;
quit;
```

One of the big advantages of this is that you can add additional types without having to worry about the function's code - just add a row to pull_list and it works.  If you want to set it up to do that, I recommend using something other than 1,2,3,4 for typenum - use 10,20,30,40 or something so you have gaps (say, if "twoweek" is added, it would be between 2 and 3, and 25 is easier than 2.5 for people to think about).  Create that pull_list dataset, put it on a network drive where all of your users can use it (if anybody beyond you uses it, or a personal one if not), and go from there.

Comment: This is also really good for learning.  Thank you, I'm going to try this method for another small project I need to do later.